# How can I validate a survey based on form elements type?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that consist of different form elements (radio, text, select) and  is dynamically created in PHP. However, I'm trying to validate this form in JQuery based on the  question type. My questions are named q1, q2,.....

```
$(function(){
        if ($('form').length > 0) {
            $('form').submit(function(e){
        var len = <?php echo $numRows; ?>; // refers to the number of rows in questions table of a database
        for (var i = 1; i <= len; i++ ) {
            var qNum = 'q'+i;
            //document.write(qNum);
            if (($('input[name=' + qNum + ']:checked').length == 0) )
            {
                if ($('input[type=Radio][name=' + qNum + ']')) {
                    alert("No Selection is made for "+ qNum);
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }           
            }); // form submit function

        }// form.length
    })//function
```

The above code handles radio buttons efficiently. However, when it comes to non radio questions it still display an alert message to that non radio question. Anyway, of handling this differently based on the question type?

Comment: Yes, but, first realize that you're mixing PHP and JS - in other words, doing code generation with the two most edge-casey languages of, well, pretty much all time. The first step is to back away from that abyss. You don't want to go there. (but to answer your question, lose the PHP-generated count, and iterate over only radio fields via pure jquery seletors instead. It's that counter-based iteration that's blithely checking all form fields instead of only radio ones.)

Comment: even though, how could I validate a form with different form element types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        if ($('form').length > 0) {
            $('form').submit(function(e){
                var answers = '';
                //alert (qNum);
        var i = 1;
        var len = <?php echo $numRows; ?>;
                $('input[type=Radio]:checked').each(function() {
                    if (answers !== '') {
                        answers += ',';
                    }
                    answers += $(this).val();
            //alert(answers);
                })
                $('input[name=h2]').val(answers);       
        for (var i = 1; i <= len; i++ ) {
            var qNum = 'q'+i;
            //document.write(qNum);
            if (($('input[name='+qNum+']:checked').length == 0) )
            {
                if ($('#'+qNum+'').is(':radio')) {
                    alert("No Selection is made for "+ qNum);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }           
            }); // form submit function

        }// form.length
    })//function
```